# Rails 4 - Google Maps with gmaps4rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am trying to figure out how to use gmaps4rails gem in my Rails 4 app.

I have a view partial in which I have inserted the 3 script tags shown in the documentation, replacing the API key with my own (which is stored in my environment secrets file).

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&key=ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']"></script>
```

I think I may have done this incorrectly, because I can't currently load maps. The error message I see when I inspect the console from Chrome is:

```
util.js:220 Google Maps API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key
```

Can anyone see if I have made an error in the way I have inserted my API key to this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting a ruby snippet into a `.html.erb` file, so u need the `<%=%>` to interpolate the ruby string

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&key=<%= ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'] %>"></script>
```

Check inspect element of ur html page to see that the url is interpolated correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Vic - I tried this, I'm still getting the invalid api keys error I set out above, but at least its not because I've incorrectly entered the api key

Comment: Good to hear! That should mean the api key is wrong is some way...maybe spelling, wrong key, wrong project's key, used ios key instead of server key? Just guessing some of the mistakes i made last time using Google API :) happy debugging haha!